# Apache2 in ubuntu unable to start

Tags: apache2, php

I am trying to start Apache server. It throws me the below error.

I was installing Magento instance here, it was working fine, but once after I created the `magento.conf` file i get this error.

I now deleted the `conf` file, but the Apache still is not able to start.

Please help me with the error log

```
apache2.serviceJob for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

The error log says:

```
[Tue Sep 27 07:35:01.408250 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 2870] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Sep 27 07:35:01.408279 2016] [core:notice] [pid 2870] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Tue Sep 27 17:29:07.403562 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 2870] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Sep 27 17:29:08.495240 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 17005] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Sep 27 17:29:08.495311 2016] [core:notice] [pid 17005] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Tue Sep 27 17:45:45.255954 2016] [:error] [pid 17010] [client 10.20.22.147:38989] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_pconnect() in /var/www/html/mindprice/system/database/drivers/mysql/mysql_driver.php:91\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/mindprice/system/database/DB_driver.php(115): CI_DB_mysql_driver->db_pconnect()\n#1 /var/www/html/mindprice/system/database/DB.php(148): CI_DB_driver->initialize()\n#2 /var/www/html/mindprice/system/core/Loader.php(346): DB(Array, NULL)\n#3 /var/www/html/mindprice/system/core/Loader.php(1171): CI_Loader->database()\n#4 /var/www/html/mindprice/system/core/Loader.php(152): CI_Loader->_ci_autoloader()\n#5 /var/www/html/mindprice/system/core/Controller.php(51): CI_Loader->initialize()\n#6 /var/www/html/mindprice/system/core/CodeIgniter.php(308): CI_Controller->__construct()\n#7 /var/www/html/mindprice/index.php(199): require_once('/var/www/html/m...')\n#8 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/mindprice/system/database/drivers/mysql/mysql_driver.php on line 91
[Tue Sep 27 17:45:45.628330 2016] [:error] [pid 17009] [client 10.20.22.147:38990] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_pconnect() in /var/www/html/mindprice/system/database/drivers/mysql/mysql_driver.php:91\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/mindprice/system/database/DB_driver.php(115): CI_DB_mysql_driver->db_pconnect()\n#1 /var/www/html/mindprice/system/database/DB.php(148): CI_DB_driver->initialize()\n#2 /var/www/html/mindprice/system/core/Loader.php(346): DB(Array, NULL)\n#3 /var/www/html/mindprice/system/core/Loader.php(1171): CI_Loader->database()\n#4 /var/www/html/mindprice/system/core/Loader.php(152): CI_Loader->_ci_autoloader()\n#5 /var/www/html/mindprice/system/core/Controller.php(51): CI_Loader->initialize()\n#6 /var/www/html/mindprice/system/core/CodeIgniter.php(308): CI_Controller->__construct()\n#7 /var/www/html/mindprice/index.php(199): require_once('/var/www/html/m...')\n#8 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/mindprice/system/database/drivers/mysql/mysql_driver.php on line 91
[Tue Sep 27 17:45:45.750438 2016] [:error] [pid 17011] [client 10.20.22.147:38991] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_pconnect() in /var/www/html/mindprice/system/database/drivers/mysql/mysql_driver.php:91\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/mindprice/system/database/DB_driver.php(115): CI_DB_mysql_driver->db_pconnect()\n#1 /var/www/html/mindprice/system/database/DB.php(148): CI_DB_driver->initialize()\n#2 /var/www/html/mindprice/system/core/Loader.php(346): DB(Array, NULL)\n#3 /var/www/html/mindprice/system/core/Loader.php(1171): CI_Loader->database()\n#4 /var/www/html/mindprice/system/core/Loader.php(152): CI_Loader->_ci_autoloader()\n#5 /var/www/html/mindprice/system/core/Controller.php(51): CI_Loader->initialize()\n#6 /var/www/html/mindprice/system/core/CodeIgniter.php(308): CI_Controller->__construct()\n#7 /var/www/html/mindprice/index.php(199): require_once('/var/www/html/m...')\n#8 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/mindprice/system/database/drivers/mysql/mysql_driver.php on line 91
[Tue Sep 27 17:45:59.627748 2016] [:error] [pid 17012] [client 10.20.22.147:38992] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_pconnect() in /var/www/html/mindprice/system/database/drivers/mysql/mysql_driver.php:91\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/mindprice/system/database/DB_driver.php(115): CI_DB_mysql_driver->db_pconnect()\n#1 /var/www/html/mindprice/system/database/DB.php(148): CI_DB_driver->initialize()\n#2 /var/www/html/mindprice/system/core/Loader.php(346): DB(Array, NULL)\n#3 /var/www/html/mindprice/system/core/Loader.php(1171): CI_Loader->database()\n#4 /var/www/html/mindprice/system/core/Loader.php(152): CI_Loader->_ci_autoloader()\n#5 /var/www/html/mindprice/system/core/Controller.php(51): CI_Loader->initialize()\n#6 /var/www/html/mindprice/system/core/CodeIgniter.php(308): CI_Controller->__construct()\n#7 /var/www/html/mindprice/index.php(199): require_once('/var/www/html/m...')\n#8 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/mindprice/system/database/drivers/mysql/mysql_driver.php on line 91
```

I don't understand what this error means.

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34599244/uncaught-error-call-to-undefined-function-mysql-connect

Comment: A simple Google search goes a long way: https://www.google.com/search?q=Uncaught+Error%3A+Call+to+undefined+function+mysql_pconnect()&oq=Uncaught+Error%3A+Call+to+undefined+function+mysql_pconnect()&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Also see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34557221/php-undefined-function-mysql-connect

Comment: If you're using PHP 7, that ^^^ might be the problem

Comment: Will you give the text out put of: `apachectl -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS`?

Comment: It was working in php 7 before too and im using msqli... And the error is mysql_pconnect() which I dint understand

Comment: How to get the dump of it @L D James

Comment: Ok thanks, @L D James...i just typed in the command apachectl -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS, i got some file was not found, i removed and its started